# any way to limit the flutter web browser width and user can not reduce the browser more than what i set?

Tags: flutter, dart

as you read from subject , i try different thing such as Flutter Web Frame  plug in .. but without success , i html and css it very easy , how i can apply in flutter web to enforce a minimum browser width size ..  i use this code for example `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_frame/flutter_web_frame.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyAp());
}

class MyAp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterWebFrame(
      builder: (context) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Flutter Web Frame'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text('Body Text'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      maximumSize: Size(475.0, 812.0), // Maximum size
      enabled: kIsWeb, // default is enable, when disable content is full size
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey, // Background color/white space
    );
  }
}`
```

all this with out success, can i limit it by editing index after compile code for web ?

regard for you all